# iOS5 Safari only attached a date picker to one input element

Tags: html, css, forms, ios5, datepicker

In the following code on a web page only displays the iPhone Date picker on the first input.

```
<form action="#" method="post" ...>
    <input type="date" name="date-from" placeholder="10/08/2012"> 
    <input type="date" name="date-to" placeholder="10/08/2012">
</form>
```

Has anyone else come across this? I'm guessing it is a mobile Safari bug rather but I can't find anyone else with the same problem nor any documentation on only the first date field having the date picker attached to it.

Screenshot below for reference

[image: Screenshot of iPhone 4S, iOS5]

Comment: What have you tried?  What happens if you swap position? What happens if you remove each one separately?  What happens if you add a third one?  Just trying to focus on what the bug could be.

Comment: Thanks, swapping the elements and looking again at the code and there was a duplicate type attribute, which should have been id...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the development code again, a duplicate type attribute was overriding the initial declaration. Rookie error!